# What type of password is this?

Tags: passwords, password-recovery

I am migrating my website from magento to wordpress-shopp site and i have to sync all the products, orders, customers. I did manage to sync all this and I am trying to keep same password of my customers and for that I want to know what type of password is this "10d32f6e654e8a54062325962f7419d5:45" is it MD5 or MD4 or any other format.

Comment: Or maybe both of them?! md5(md4(password));

Comment: Or neither of them or something else! As far as we can see it's just a string of what appears to be random characters.

Comment: @Keyur - Look at the source code for Magento and modify the Wordpress code to use the same hashing mechanic. I suggest you force a password change on your users, md5 hashing, is not proper for storing password. If your database was compromised it would be trivial to determine your user's password ( ar at least the string that generated the same hash ).

Comment: @Ramhound Even though MD5 has been unacceptable for passwords since years now, it's still commonly used. It's not unlikely to find MD5-hashed passwords these days—or even plaintext passwords, unfortunately.

Comment: @slhck - Which is the reason I suggested the author allows Wordpress to use the better password hashing mechanic instead of using Megento's md5 + salt password hashing mechanic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento uses MD5 hashes, which are salted and stored in the database as a combination of:

```
hash:salt
```

So in your case, `10d32f6e654e8a54062325962f7419d5` is the hash and `45` is the salt.

Reference: [How are passwords encrypted in Magento | MagentoGarden Blog](http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/how-are-passwords-encrypted-in-magento.html)